# Как удалить определенную строку и столбец матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, матрицы, динамические-массивы

Задача: вывести и решить минор матрицы по заданным индексам строки и столбца. С решением проблем не возникло, а вот *как получить определенный минор*? *Как вычеркнуть определённые столбец и строку*?

Comment: Скопировать в матрицу меньшего размера все элементы, кроме тех, что находятся в вычеркнутых столбце и строке.

Comment: как непосредственно игнорировать определённые столбец и строку

Comment: покажите как у вас реализован массив. `int m[2][2];` или `int * m[2];` или `int * * m ;`  или `std::array<std::array<int,2>,2>` или `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` ???

Comment: ''int **a; 'int m; a = new int* [m];
         for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
              a[i] = new int [n];
         for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
              for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                   a[i][j] = 0; '''

Answer (score 2):

Отдельным циклами сделать несложно

```
 for (int i=0;i<row;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
        B[i][j] = A[i][j];
    for (int j=col+1;j<col_count;j++)
        B[i][j-1] = A[i][j];
 }
 for (int i=row+1;i<row_count;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<col_count;j++)
        B[i-1][j] = A[i][j];
    for (int j=col+1;j<col_count;j++)
        B[i-1][j-1] = A[i][j];
 }
```

А можно по ходу дела индекс корректировать

```
 for (int i=0;i<row_count;i++) {
    rowshift = (i>row)?1:0; 
    for (int j=0;j<col;j++) {
        colshift = (j>col)?1:0; 
        B[i-rowshift][j-colshift] = A[i][j];
    }
 }
```

Если в C++ логические выражения приводятся к int 0 и 1, то это можно прямо внутрь квадратных скобок вставить